# Create a new Nintendo Network ID

Tags: nintendo-network-id

I'm not quite happy with my NNID I registered initially, and I want to change it. I'm planning to register a new NNID user, unlink current user from Nintendo Club, link new user to Nintendo Club. As far as I know I still will have access to all purchases I've made using it, while old user will be registered on the system.

Is there some other potential problems I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I've completed operations as planned and everything seems working as expected. Suppose you want to use new `NewName` as a *primary* NNID instead of old `OldName` with a possible minimum impact.

1. Register a new `NewName` user on a console, and follow standard procedure of creating new Mii and NNID. You can use same email as for `OldName` user.
2. Under `OldName` user, launch eShop and unlink Nintendo Club if necessary.
3. Under `NewName` user, launch eShop and link Nintendo Club if necessary.
4. Under `NewName` user, in user switch menu select `Make Default`.

That's it! You can still access all purchases made under `OldName`. Of course you lose all information associated with old account, most notably including save games (however some games have `shared` save files which are user-independent), friends and all Miiverse data. But as long as you keep old user you can always switch back to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Linking your IDs is permanent. Additionally, deleting the NNID will delete everything. 
[Deleting a Nintendo ID](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2224)
This includes licenses and wallet balance.

Unlinking your NNID from your Club Nintendo account may be possible. These are the steps taken from a call a customer had with a Nintendo Representative regarding the issue:

```
1. On the Wii U Menu, select the Nintendo eShop icon.

2. Select "Menu" or press the Y button.

3. Select "Settings/Other."

4. Select "Club Nintendo Account."

5. Select the box under "Club Nintendo Account," and enter your user name, and then select "OK."

6. Select the box under "Password," and enter your password, and then select "OK."

7. Select "Link" to link the Club Nintendo and Nintendo eShop accounts together.

8. To unlink a Club Nintendo account, follow steps 1-4 above, then select "Remove" twice.
```

Original can be found [here](http://techforums.nintendo.com/thread/18269).

If you really want to change your name, I'd say your best bet is to call Nintendo.

Comment: I do not want do delete a NNID, I wand to create another one and leave the existing. Is that not possible?